# C++ Creating a standalone library in linux and using it in another program

Tags: linux, eclipse, shared-libraries

I'm trying to create a shared library for Linux such that:

- other programs can use its functions and its objects
- the code is not visible to final user

What i did is create a shared library with Eclipse. This library uses pthreads.
I generated .so and .lib. The .lib is in LIBRARY/Lib while the .so is in LIBRARY/Release.

Then i created another project which should use this library and i gave the path of the .lib file and the path of the .h file which only contains the inclusions of all the necessary .h of the library.
All seems working but when i run the program it crashes. When debugging it I receive the following message:

> Can't find a source file at "pthread_mutex_lock.c"
>
> Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.

What's wrong? Can someone help me please?

EDIT: I changed nothing and now I have a different error, some lines before the previous:

> Can't find a source file at "random.c"
>
> Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.

Comment: Install the libpthread development and debugging packages (usually part of "glibc-debug" or similar).

Comment: I have all the libraries installed. The projects was under Netbeans as "standalone program" and worked good. Then I decided to move it under Eclipse and transform it to a library and this is the problem I'm having

Comment: `pthread_mutex_lock.c` is a file from the pthreads library. You are probably calling a function in that file, most likely `pthread_mutex_lock()`. You may try to install the glibc *sources* package, but first try to go up the stack and see if you can examine your own code. Perhaps you will be able to see an error there. An error in `pthread_mutex_lock()` that leads to a crash is unlikely to surface.

Comment: I already installed all the necessary libraries and the project worked under Netbeans as standalone. I probably made something wrong in the project settings in Eclipse but I cannot understand what.

Comment: Make sure that you initialize the pthread mutex and also be sure not to use the mutex in a constructor.

Comment: You're right cowboy! I made a mistake while converting it from a standalone program to a shared library and I don't initialize the pthread! Then, being new to shared libraries and Eclipse I was looking for another problem, but the error was simply instead. Thank you. However, why do you say to not to use a mutex in a constructor?

Answer (score 0):

> - other programs can use its functions and its objects
> - the code is not visible to final user

These two goals directly contradict each other, and achieving both at the same time is *impossible* on Linux.

If some program can use your library, then I can write a new program that can do so as well.